# git hook allowing merge only of branch with a single commit

Tags: git, githooks

In the repository I use only a single commit per branch is allowed. In case of multiple commits, rebase is needed before merging.. since failing is human I use to forget this.

I would like to implement a git-hook that checks on a merge request whether the branch which is merged into development has a single commit or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Tell us what you have done, write the code, and if you're having problem with it then ask a specific question.

Comment: @LubošTurek Thanks for the advice. I have no Idea how to do this and was looking for help. I do not expect you to write code for me, rather then a hint or help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing a hook on remote then You can use the update hook to run  to list the differing commits then work with the count of lines in the output. 
old_hash and new_hash are passed as arguments to this hook which are the existing and the new commit hashes. Git will call this hook as

`"$GIT_DIR/hooks/update refname old_hash new_hash"`

Here is a sample, you can insert `git rev-list --merges ${1}~1..${1}` to determine if it is a merge commit

```
case "$1" in
  refs/heads/*)
    is_merge = $(git rev-list --merges ${1}~1..${1})
    if [ ! -z "${is_merge}" ]; then 
        commit_count = $(git rev-list $2..$3 | wc -l)
        if [ ${commit_count} > 1 ]; then
            echo <reject with your message>
            exit 1
        fi
    else
       <Not a merge commit do other validations>
    fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Looks promissing. I was wondering if the snipped to estimate if it's a commit is needed. I found in the `update.sample` example hook that `case` is called with `"$refname","$newrev_type"` and you thus should be able to check for `refs/heads/*,commit`

Comment: Yeah but in your local repository a merge may not create a commit if it is fast forwarded. So it is reliable to check on remote.